# Nodejs core module fs is not working with webpack and angular2 cli

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

The fs is an empty object in my app.

I am using Angular2 cli which uses webpack to bundle up the application.
I am using the file-exists package in my app - https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-exists.
So in my component.ts file, I have this line:

```
let fileExists = require('file-exists');
```

This file-exists package in turn has this line:

```
fs.statSync(fullpath).isFile();
```

But this fs is always just an empty object. Am not sure what is going on.. 
i.e is Webpack not including in fs which is node's core package ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fileExists in a browser ? have no sense for me

Comment: There is no browser implementation for fs in webpack. See this list: https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/README.md. How would you expect that to even work client side?

Comment: Ah true.. I feel like a fool.. was so intent on trying to see why fs is not working, forgot about how file exists would work on client side. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file-exists`, depends on `fs`. There is no webpack polyfill for `fs` and there wouldn't be a good way to add one either. Therefore webpack can't export `file-exists` for client-side web usage.  See [this list](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/README.md) for supported, native, node modules that can be polyfilled.